# copy contents from sample json file to index elastic search index json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch

elastic search version i am using 6.6.1

i have created  index by running following command
curl -XPUT  http://localhost:9200/incident_422? -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @elasticsearch.json

i need to update the index file with sample json data.(sample.json)

```
{
    "properties": {
        "id185": {
            "type": "byte"
    },
    "id255": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "id388": {
      "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried running the command
curl -XPUT  http://localhost:9200/incident_422/mapping/_doc? -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @sample.json

but i get the error message saying that
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [incident_422] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [mapping, doc]"}]

i have read somewhere that ELK 6 doesnt support more than two types.

Could anyone please tell me how this can be achieved without downgrading the version

Answer (score 0):

This seems to related to the [removal of mapping type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), you need to specify the type name while indexing the documents.

try adding type to your index request aka `http://localhost:9200/incident_422/<your-type-name>` in your URL and it should solve the issue.

Comment: tried this curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/incident_597/mapping/_doc?' -d @sample.json   gives same error

Comment: @ManjushaS, please remove mapping from your URL and try again

Comment: tried curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/incident_422/_doc?' -d @sample.json
now i get {"error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/incident_422/_doc?] and method [PUT], allowed: [POST]","status":405}

Comment: @ManjushaS, can you try with POST HTTP method??

Comment: getting this now {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [incident_422] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [incident_422] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"},"status":400}    after running    curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/incident_422/_doc?' -d @sample.json

Comment: @ManjushaS, looks like `doc` type is already created in your index, can you please delete it ??

Comment: @ManjushaS use `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/incident_422/doc`

Comment: @ManjushaS any luck?